# How to use existing AWS internal load balancer for exposing multiple Kubernetes services

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, internal-load-balancer, kubernetes-service

I am using Kubernetes deployed using KOPS in AWS. For exposing few services , I have couple of AWS internal load balancer for TCP ports like 22 , 389. These TCP ports can't be used in ingress-controller like Nginx. So for exposing these TCP ports for each deployment , I am using AWS LB. AWS has a limit on number of load balancers per region.

I am looking for a solution to use one aws internal load balancer for multiple services. For example : One AWS LB can use for port 22 , 80 , 389 and send traffic to internal Kubernetes POD using POD internal ports. Using this solution I can minimize my number of AWS LB and expose multiple services pointing to single LB. Any comments are appreciated .

Thanks 
Sas

Comment: If you are OK with not using your ningx ingress controller: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller. Basically with this setup, traffic through your K8 AWS ALB will hit your ingress pod and then to your service. If you are not having hundreds of K8 services you want to expose this should work.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/  (ingresses might already support tcp/udp services through annotations) - If so you probably can just point the ELB to that single nginx-controller

Comment: Thanks both of you. Let me try both solutions .